# How to achieve basic authentication in mule soft project?

Tags: mule, basic-authentication, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, cloudhub

We have developed mule projects using AnyPoint Studio 6.1.0. We deploy these in cloudhub and access them using https urls. If it is POST method we pass JSON data and get the response. Here we are trying to provide security to the deployed app URLs so that end users must provide username and password to access these URLs.

Can anyone of you help us to implement security to Mule projects deployed to Cloudhub.For example, basic authentication security mechanism or any other ?

Answer (score 0):

Mule uses Spring Security for authentication.

Detailed user guide: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/configuring-the-spring-security-manager
This has  an example of the `http-security-filter` that you need to put in the HTTP inbound endpoint.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

you need to use security manager to create a basic auth,Use the below spring beans in your mule configuration file.

```
<spring:beans>
    <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
      <ss:authentication-provider>
        <ss:user-service id="userService">
          <ss:user name="user" password="password" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
          <ss:user name="anon" password="anon" authorities="ROLE_ANON" />
        </ss:user-service>
      </ss:authentication-provider>
    </ss:authentication-manager>
  </spring:beans>

  <mule-ss:security-manager>
      <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider name="memory-provider" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
  </mule-ss:security-manager>
```

And after your http componenet add the basic auth

```
 <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
                <http:basic-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/>
```